# Entity Framework - Programmatically add FunctionImportMapping

Tags: entity-framework

How to add a FunctionImportMapping programmatically using classes from the System.Data.Entity.Design namespace?

This blog post discusses the modifications that need to be made to the EDMX:

http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2007/09/14/how-to-map-stored-procedures-using-the-ado-net-entity-framework.aspx

I want to be able to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the metadata APIs (i.e. the ones that reason about the CSDL/MSL/SSDL) are read-only. So unless you write your own API to help you create appropriate XML, you are out of luck.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: I figured.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: EF v4 will support "Code Only" EDMs that may be modifiable at runtime.

Comment: Well the EDM might be modifyable at runtime, the class upon which the model is based, are not. So you are limited to a sub-set of what your CLR classes define.